# How to pass Data multiple Sheet in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

This code works very well for me. But I need to add 2 more .sheet in this page. When I try to other solutions list cell doesnt pass to data correctly. How do I improve this code for 3 sheet?

```
@State var selectedUser: User?

     List...
        UserCell(user: user)
            .onTapGesture {
                 self.selectedUser = user
                        }

.sheet(item: self.$selectedUser) { user in
    DetailView(user: user)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by three sheets? Would you show demo? In general you can use same one sheet, but just pass different items inside, eg. enum with different stored types and show view corresponding to that data. It is really very rare case when in one body might be needed several sheets.

Comment: in View, I have a list and data. First:  I want to add data to the list but I dont want to use navigationlink. I want to open the  sheet with a button in the navigationBarItems.(AdItemView). Second: when I tap to list cell, I want to show DetailView (This is a different view and need to pass cell data). Third: I want to edit cell data. When I tab to context menu, I want to open EditView. Add and edit View is different because I have some reason in my project.

Answer (score 2):

`NavigationView` has only one `sheet` per `view`, so data in sheet instead multiple sheets as in your list;
add one `sheet` to your `view` change data on tap, like in below code;

```
 enum SheetType {
    case preview
    case edit
    case yourAnyChoice
 }

struct ContentView:View{
  @State var selectedUser:String = "" 
  @State var showingDetail = false
  @State var sheetType:SheetType = SheetType.preview
  var body: some View {
  List(userList){in user
      HStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.selectedUser = user.name
                self.sheetType = .preview
                self.showingDetail.toggle()
            }){
             Text("name")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.selectedUser = user.name
                self.sheetType = .edit
                self.showingDetail.toggle()
            }){
             Text("edit")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.selectedUser = user.name
                self.sheetType = .yourAnyChoice
                self.showingDetail.toggle()
            }){
             Text("yourAction")
            }
        }
   }
   .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingDetail){
   detailView(text:self.$selectedUser,type:self.$sheetType)
   }
  }

struct detailView:View {
  @Binding var text:String
  @Binding var type:SheetType
  var body:some View{
    if type == SheetType.preview{
      Text(text)
    }
    if type == .edit {
       yourEditingView() // as per your requirements 
     }
    if type == SheetType.yourAnyChoice{
      yourChoiceViews()
        }
    
}
```

Comment: I can present more than one sheet in swiftUI but I couldn't pass to data. You can check here. [Multiple Sheet!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58837261/14139338)

Comment: Did you test it ? it pass data to sheet when you tap on row

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I created to variable and try to pass in. sheet shows only first index in list.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like you to read the question again. The above code is already working for me. Besides, I want to run 2 different sheets.

Comment: what do meant by 2 different sheet? differ by appearance, like background color, text color etc, the sheet already displaying data of the row of user tap, that's different by row

Comment: I need to present 3 sheet. 1 cellDetail - 2 contextmenu(edit cell) - 3 present new view. 2 view need pass data