# .fullScreenCover always opening same Detail Page

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

so I'm having a bit of an issue here I'm hoping is easy to fix, just can't figure it out at the moment. I'm running a loop through some CoreData info (posts) and returning a grid of images, I want to be able to click these images and open up a fullScreenCover of the DetailView with the correct info in it. With the current code, the DetailView always shows the data from the first post. If I change it from a Button to a NavigationLink `NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(post: post))`, as commented out in the code, it works perfectly, but doesn't give me the fullScreenCover behaviour I would like. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Post.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var posts: FetchedResults<Post>

enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        case detail, addNew
        
        var id: Int {
            hashValue
        }
    }
@State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?

var body: some View {

ForEach(posts.reversed(), id: \.self) { post in
    
    VStack {
    Button(action: { activeSheet = .detail }){
    //NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(post: post)){
    ZStack {
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: post.mainImage ?? self.image)!)
        VStack {
        Text("\(post.title)")
        Text("\(post.desc)")
        }
    }
}
.fullScreenCover(item: $activeSheet) { item in
            switch item {
            case .detail:
                DetailView(post: post)
            case .addNew:
                AddNewView()
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: It's best practice to avoid any conditional logic within the .sheet and .fullScreenCover closure. Solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416673/multiple-bottom-sheets-the-content-doesnt-load-swiftui/65416999#65416999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made the array of posts static for now instead of coming from Core Data and mocked the objects/structs so that I could test easily, but the principal should stay the same:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    //@FetchRequest(entity: Post.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var posts: FetchedResults<Post>
    var posts : [Post] = [Post(title: "1", desc: "desc1"),
                          Post(title: "2", desc: "desc2"),
                          Post(title: "3", desc: "desc3")]
    
    enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
        case detail(post: Post)
        case addNew
        
        var id: UUID {
            switch self {
            case .detail(let post):
                return post.id
            default:
                return UUID()
            }
        }
    }
    @State var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(posts.reversed(), id: \.self) { post in
            
            VStack {
                Button(action: { activeSheet = .detail(post: post) }){
                    ZStack {
                        //Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: post.mainImage ?? self.image)!)
                        VStack {
                            Text("\(post.title)")
                            Text("\(post.desc)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(item: $activeSheet) { item in
                switch item {
                case .detail(let post):
                    DetailView(post: post)
                case .addNew:
                    AddNewView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var post: Post
    
    var body : some View {
        Text("Detail \(post.id)")
    }
}

struct AddNewView : View {
    var body : some View {
        Text("add")
    }
}

struct Post : Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var desc : String
}
```

The basic idea is that instead of creating the `fullScreenCover` on first render, you should create it in based on the `activeSheet` so that it gets created dynamically. You were on the right track using `item:` and `activeSheet` already -- the problem was it wasn't tied to the actual post, since you were just using the button to set `activeSheet = .detail`.

I've added an associated property to `case detail` that allows you to actually tie a post to it. Then, in `fullScreenCover` you can see that I use that associated value when creating the `DetailView`.

You may have to make slight adjustments to fit your `Post` model, but the concept will remain the same.