# Use a Full Screen Cover within a View with a Full Screen Cover

Tags: swift, swiftui, modal-dialog

I have a parent view covering the entire screen that has a `.fullScreenCover`. That parent view contains several child views with all the details of the 'page'. One of those child views contains an element that also has a `.fullScreenCover` control.

```swift
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var isPresent = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Other children
            ChildView()
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresent: self.$isPresent) {
            CoverView()
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @State var isPresent = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello", action: { self.isPresent = true })
            .fullScreenView(isPresent: self.$isPresent) {
                ChildCoverView()
            }
    }
}
```

The screen cover for the parent view opens as expected, but when I try to open the screen cover from the child view, nothing happens. If I remove the `.fullScreenCover` control from the parent view, then the child screen view does work, so it must have something to do with the nesting and all.

Is there a way to get a child `.fullScreenCover` to work inside a parent view that also has a `.fullScreenCover`?

Comment: It's the same with `sheet` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58837007/14351818) --- a bug. Coincidentally, it was fixed 2 days ago in Xcode 12.5.0 Beta 3.

Comment: @Caleb : You do not need wait for fix the bug, you can make a custom View with same functionality of fullScreenCover or sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was/is a bug preventing this from working until iOS 14.5 beta 3.

From the release notes (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-14_5-beta-release-notes):

> You can now apply multiple sheet(isPresented:onDismiss:content:) and fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:) modifiers in the same view hierarchy. (74246633)

The workaround until then is to present from a common ancestor or present the parent fullScreenCover on a different branch of the view tree (ie one that doesn't contain the child view):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isPresent = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Other children
            ChildView() //branch 1
            Button("Present Parent") { //branch 2
                isPresent.toggle()
            }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$isPresent) {
                Text("hello")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    @State var isPresent = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Present child", action: { self.isPresent = true })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$isPresent) {
                Text("world")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is still happening on ios17+

This fixed it for me, thanks!