# Use ForEach to make Unique Sheets on Button Press in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, foreach, swiftui

[I was looking here at this to try to solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58837007/multiple-sheetispresented-doesnt-work-in-swiftui), and many said that this was fixed in the latest XCode version, but it is not working for me and I am on the latest public XCode version that supports iOS 14.5. I have a few arrays that each contain info such as a name, number, and description. I want each of these to appear as buttons and then when tapped on to show a sheet with a unique view to that button.

Here is a shortened example of one of my arrays:

```
var discussionTask = [
        Task(taskname: "Pick Up Around Your City", taskdescription: "Pick up and recycle litter", sfsymbolname: "trash.slash.fill", tokencount: 15),
        Task(taskname: "Go Paperless", taskdescription: "When possible, opt to use a digital device over paper.", sfsymbolname: "trash.slash.fill", tokencount: 15),
        Task(taskname: "Plant a Tree", taskdescription: "Plant a tree.", sfsymbolname: "leaf.fill", tokencount: 15)
    ]
```

With this example array, I would want to make a button for each `Task`, so in this case there would be 3 buttons. The first button should show the name "Pick Up Around Your City" and have the number "15". When clicked on, I want it to show all of the data including the `taskdescription` and `sfsymbol`.

Everything that I currently try only shows the first item in the sorted array, but I want it to show a unique sheet for each button. And instead of just three items in the list there are many more that I will continue to add to. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
func DiscussionTrackViewButton(tasknumber: Int) -> some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            print(tasknumber)
            showTaskSheet = true
        }, label: {
            TrackBlockView(sfimagename: discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].sfsymbolname, taskname: discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].taskname, tokencount: String(discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].tokencount)) 
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showTaskSheet) {
            DetailedTrackView(sfsymbolname: discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].sfsymbolname, taskname: discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].taskname, taskdetails: discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].taskdescription, tokencount: discussionTask.sorted { $0.taskname < $1.taskname }[tasknumber].tokencount, trackData: $trackdata, DailyGoalProgress: $DailyGoalProgress, TabSelection: $TabSelection, SavedDailyGoal: $SavedDailyGoal, DateSinceStreak: $DateSinceStreak, DaysOfStreak: $DaysOfStreak)
        }
            
        
    }
```

Here is where I call the function:

```
ForEach(0..<discussionTask.count) { index in
                                    DiscussionTrackViewButton(tasknumber: index)
                                 }
```

In this case it prints the unique `tasknumber` and the buttons are all unique. However, any time I click on any button, it only shows the first sorted item's info. For context, `DetailedTrackView` is just the detailed info screen that I want to appear. Why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
struct DiscussionTaskView: View {
    var discussionTasks = [
        Task(taskname: "Pick Up Around Your City", taskdescription: "Pick up and recycle litter", sfsymbolname: "trash.slash.fill", tokencount: 15),
        Task(taskname: "Go Paperless", taskdescription: "When possible, opt to use a digital device over paper.", sfsymbolname: "trash.slash.fill", tokencount: 15),
        Task(taskname: "Plant a Tree", taskdescription: "Plant a tree.", sfsymbolname: "leaf.fill", tokencount: 15)
    ]
    
    @State var selectedTask: Task?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(discussionTasks) { task in
                Button {
                    selectedTask = task
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: task.sfsymbolname)
                }
                .sheet(item: $selectedTask) { task in
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                        Text(task.taskname)
                            .font(.headline)
                        Text(task.taskdescription)
                        Text("\(task.tokencount)")
                        Image(systemName: task.sfsymbolname)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the `.sheet(item:content:)` version of the `sheet` modifier to display each item as its corresponding button is tapped.

It also assumes your `Task` struct conforms to `Identifiable`, which would not be hard to do if it is not already.