# State is nil when showing sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For some reason, my selectedTask State is Empty when presenting the Sheet,
even if I set it on the onTapGesture.
What I'm I missing?

```
struct TasksTabView: View {

    @State private var showComputedTaskSheet: Bool = false
    @State var selectedTask: OrderTaskCheck?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(tasks.enumerated()), id:\.1.title) { (index, task) in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 40) {
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            PillForRow(index: index, task: task)
                        }.padding(.bottom, 30)
                    }.onTapGesture {
                        // Where I'm setting selectedTask
                        self.selectedTask = task
                        self.showComputedTaskSheet.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showComputedTaskSheet) {
        // self.selectedTask is returns nil
        showScreen(task: self.selectedTask!)
    }
    .onAppear {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63181811/14351818

Comment: @aheze: using item is much better way! I update my answer. thanks

Comment: @swiftPunk in this case item can't be a State. It needs to be a Binding Value

Comment: @John: I updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I have no access to your full project this example can help you to get the idea, you can use `.sheet()` with **item** initializer like **aheze** said.

*The advantage is here you pass optional to input item and you receive unwrapped safe value to work!*

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var customValue: CustomValue?
    
    var body: some View {

        Button("Show the Sheet View") { customValue = CustomValue(description: "Hello, World!") }
            .sheet(item: $customValue){ item in sheetView(item: item) }
 
    }
    
    func sheetView(item: CustomValue) -> some View {
        
        return VStack {
            
            Text(item.description)
            
            Button("Close the Sheet View") { customValue = nil }.padding()
            
        }
    }
    
}

struct CustomValue: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var description: String
}
```